# Rename an image with laravel 5

Tags: file, laravel-5, rename

I have a directory with images and I show to the user,the user can rename a image, I have the file with
$images = File::files('img');
$image = $images[0];
But I don't know how rename an image.
Thanks

Comment: Can you give me the result of `print_r($image)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve it first from the input. and move it using file name you define.
Your image will using the file name you specify.

```
 $picture= $request->file('image');
 $fileName = 'what the image you want to call';
 $picture->move('image/foo', $fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Brother, This is work for me. And I hope, It'll serve your purpose

```
$destinationPath = "uploadedImages";
$newName = md5_file($request->file('file_name')->getRealPath());
$guessFileExtension = $request->file('file_name')->guessExtension();
$file = $request->file('file_name')->move($destinationPath, $newName.'.'.$guessFileExtension);
```